# How do I get about adding something to my Android Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am a complete newb to Android and have seen tutorials that show widgets being added via XML and also via Java. I want to know what industry experts prefer and why. The author/narrator seems to prefer XML saying it gives more control but I wanted to get feedback from veterans.

1. [With XML Tutorial](http://techstacked.tv/tutorial/android-tutorial-5-hello-world-app/)
2. [Without XML Tutorial](http://techstacked.tv/tutorial/android-tutorial-6-hello-world-app-using-java-and-not-xml/)

Thank You and again I apologize for a complete newb question.

Answer (score 2):

XML layouts are very easy compared to java code. The coding also very less than java.

You can prefer any of these two, but all authors prefer XML because its easy.

Please read information available at this link, you will get an idea.

[XML Layouts](http://www.androidacademy.com/1-features/40-current/183-10-things-every-android-developer-needs-to-know?start=5)

Answer (score 2):

**Declare UI elements in XML (most
common and preferred)**

Android provides a straightforward XML vocabulary
that corresponds to the View classes and subclasses,
such as those for UI controls called widgets
(TextView, Button, etc.) and layouts.

**Instantiate layout elements at
runtime (programmatically in Java code)**

Your application can create View and ViewGroup
objects (and manipulate their properties)
programmatically (in Java code).

### Advantages of : Declaring UI in XML

• **Separation of the presentation from the code
that controls its behavior**

> You can modify UI without having to modify your
>   source code and recompile
>   For example, you can create XML layouts for
>   different screen orientations, different device screen
>   sizes, and different languages

• **Easier to visualize the structure of your UI
(without writing any code)**

> Easier to design/debug UI
>   Visualizer tool (like the one in Eclipse IDE)

### Advantages of : Instantiate layout elements at runtime

• **While showing dynamic data**

> When your application need to show dynamically some information for example loading title from web then you need as many text-view per title and you are not sure at design time about this at that time this can be preffered

You can make your application design both ways and both will help you the same,It will depened on your requirement whether you require to create it at runtime or not,Anyways I think while you can make separate XML file why need to do it in your Activity java file and get more complexity in code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

XML layout method is very easy, fast and easy to visualize. You can do a paper-pencil work first and simply do it in XML.

XML layouts are easy to manage - you can change the caption, position, look & feel, size, colors etc. in the XML layout, without altering a single line of the Java Code. The App will generate the Java Code for the layout from your XML file.

XML layout **does not** compell that you should write the whole XML codes. Instead, you can use a GUI editor and you arrange the controls on screen, and it will generate the XML for you. There are lots of GUI design tools. Eg.: http://www.droiddraw.org

Now, you can go for Java Code UI layout **only if** you cannot determine the layout at the time of writing the App. Say, you are designing an Android App for Web Designers - An app to create HTML Forms and create the HTML code (a simple HTML editor tool), then you are unable to know which type of layout the user is going to do. At this point, the better option is choosing Dynamic Layout (or Java Code layout)

Almost every Android programmer chooses to do layout in XML. That's the beast and easiest way to do it.